# How to change the icons of snap programs?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, icons, themes, desktop-icons

I downloaded some themes and icons to customize my whole desktop UI and the last thing I need to change is some icons. I'm using a theme and it changed all the icons except for the programs that I either downloaded from the Ubuntu software store or using the `snap` command.

I went into the `snap` folder in the terminal and I saw a list of all the programs whose icons didn't change. I found the `.desktop` files for some of the programs, but when I use gedit and try to change the icon location, it says that it's read-only.

How can I change the permissions so that I can change the `.desktop` file? Is there an easier way to accomplish this?

See for example the Android Studio `.desktop` file contents:

[image: Android Studio .desktop]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't want to **change** the `.desktop` file installed by Snap. You cannot.
Instead, **override** the `.desktop` file with your own custom version.
([Source thread](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/overriding-desktop-files-on-ubuntu-snaps/6599/2) on snapcraft.io.)

1. The snap's `.desktop` file is located at `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/snap-name_application-name.desktop`.

   - Note the location: It will be overwritten every time the snap updates. You cannot prevent it. So DON'T bother editing this file.
2. Copy the .desktop file to: `~/.local/share/applications/snap-name_application-name.desktop`.

   - The name schema (snap-name_application-name) is critical. Don't change it.
   - Edit this copy!

Here's an example of creating an editable override copy (the *discord* application, provided by the *discord* snap):

```
$ cp \
> /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/discord_discord.desktop \
> ~/.local/share/applications/discord_discord.desktop
```

Comment: copy all .desktop files using this: `sudo cp /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/*.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/`

Comment: That will copy all desktop files. There are consequences of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Look for a program called Alacarte, "an easy-to-use menu editor for GNOME". It is in the official Ubuntu repositories. With it you can easily change the icon using GUI.