# PNG specified by .desktop file doesn't show up (20.04)

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, ubuntu-dock, desktop-icons

I have a `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications/` for one of my applications.

The file contains `Icon=/usr/share/theapplication/icon.png`. If I open `/usr/share/theapplication/`, `icon.png` is in there and it is the correct icon. When I open the "Show Applications" menu, the application shows up with the icon. However, in the dock, the icon is always blank. It just looks like this...

[image: Blank icon]

What's going on here? How can I get Ubuntu to show the actual icon for the application when it's running, instead of just a blank space?

Answer (score 1):

This could be a permissions issue if all users don't have read access to the image.

From the folder containing the icon, you can run `sudo chmod 744 icon.png` to set permissions to `rwxr--r--`.

If the application was installed using [snap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278025/how-to-change-the-icons-of-snap-programs), flatpak, or some other sandbox or pseudo-sandbox, then you should research how to create a custom icon for these applications, since they might not have access to `/usr/share`