# Grant writing permission to /snap devices

Tags: permissions, icons, snap, chmod, devices

I installed blender with snap and I want the app to use [blender's numix-circle-icon](https://github.com/numixproject/numix-icon-theme-circle/blob/master/Numix-Circle/48/apps/blender.svg) so I tried to replace `/snap/blender/47/blender.svg` but I have this error with sudo:
`File systeme is only readable` I test to chmod it but it make same error. I found those directory are mounted device from `/var/lib/snapd/snaps/` So I ask you, ***how to grant writing on snap devices & them mounted dirs?***

Comment: It's not a *permission* issue. Snaps use squashfs, which is compressed and read-only. You simply cannot change any content without re-making the entire Snap package.

Comment: However, see https://askubuntu.com/a/1278031/19626 for how to override the snap-provided .desktop file. You can point to a different icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a snap application called 'overlay' - you can install it via Snap Store. This little app makes it possible to remount a snap read/write. However, it needs to be repeated every time the system starts up, so you have to write a script that is called on system startup, which remounts the particular snap r/w using 'overlay' and copies the needed files there. (Actually you don't have to use the 'overlay' application, you can remount a snap r/w using just 'mount' command with overlayfs, but that application simplifies it).

Comment: Thanks you very much for your answer!